# Finding compiler vendor / version using qmake

Tags: c++, qt, build-process, makefile, qmake

Is there any way to get the version and vendor of the compiler used by the user through qmake? What I need is to disable building some targets of my project when g++ 3.x is used and enable them when g++ 4.x is used.

**Update:** Most answers targeted the preprocessor. This is something that I want to avoid. I don't want a target to be build for a specific compiler version and I want this decision to be made by the build system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to [ashcatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801279/finding-compiler-vendor-version-using-qmake/801769#801769)'s answer, `qmake` allows you to [query the command line](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#system-command) and get the response back as a variable.  So you could to something like this:

```
linux-g++ {
    system( g++ --version | grep -e "\<4.[0-9]" ) {
        message( "g++ version 4.x found" )
        CONFIG += g++4
    }
    else system( g++ --version | grep -e "\<3.[0-9]" ) {
        message( "g++ version 3.x found" )
        CONFIG += g++3
    }
    else {
        error( "Unknown system/compiler configuration" )
    }
}
```

Then later, when you want to use it to specify targets, you can use the config scoping rules:

```
SOURCES += blah blah2 blah3
g++4: SOURCES += blah4 blah5
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I was thinking on doing something like that but thought I 'd ask if there is something that is already supported out of the box. Since there apparently isn't your solution is ready to use :-)

Comment: @Caleb: there is a possible simplification if you would use the `gcc -dumpversion` command, which could make grep redundant. May I edit your answer or shall I write another one?

Comment: @BogdanWilli Feel free.

Comment: See below for qmake variable that exists, at least from 2020 onwards. :)

Answer (score 7):

My answer based on [Caleb Huitt - cjhuitt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807398/3045403)'s. But his approach does not work for me.

```
*-g++ {
    GCC_VERSION = $$system("g++ -dumpversion")
    contains(GCC_VERSION, 6.[0-9]) {
        message( "g++ version 6.x found" )
        CONFIG += g++6
    } else {
        contains(GCC_VERSION, 5.[0-9]) {
            message( "g++ version 5.x found" )
            CONFIG += g++5
        } else {
            contains(GCC_VERSION, 4.[0-9]) {
                message( "g++ version 4.x found" )
                CONFIG += g++4
            } else {
                message( "Unknown GCC configuration" )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see you can get version from GCC and then compare it with regex expression.

The way how to use is the same:

```
SOURCES += blah blah2 blah3
g++4: SOURCES += blah4 blah5
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to check the version once and store the result. Also note that `$$QMAKE_CXX` (for example) will return the full name of current compiler, eg. if cross-compiling. `GCC_VERSION = $$system("$${QMAKE_CXX} -dumpversion")`

Answer (score 3):

My answer is based on [dismine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813297/4304606)
We can simply extract the major version number using $$str_member

```
gcc | clang {
    COMPILER_VERSION = $$system($$QMAKE_CXX " -dumpversion")
    COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION = $$str_member($$COMPILER_VERSION)
    greaterThan(COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION, 3): message("gcc 4 or later")
    greaterThan(COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): message("gcc 5 or later")
    greaterThan(COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): message("gcc 6 or later")
    greaterThan(COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION, 6): message("gcc 7 or later")
}
```

Comment: for older Qt version str_member ist not available, but following worked for me
    COMPILER_VERSION = $$system($$QMAKE_CXX " -dumpversion")
    COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION1 = $$split(COMPILER_VERSION, ".")
    COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION = $$first(COMPILER_MAJOR_VERSION1)

Comment: fails with gcc10.  See Nightingale7's solution using split.

Answer (score 2):

As a start, I would look at the scoping feature that qmake supports:

[Scopes and Conditions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions)

But while I read about it, it seems that by default you can use general platform conditions like `win32` or `unix` or you can use the name of the qmake spec like `linux-g++`. You could test the Visual Studio version like this (since the different Visual Studio versions use different qmake specs), but I don't think that you can test the gcc version like this (at least I don't know how).

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant but not so well documented feature as described on topic on [QT forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/116671/how-to-detect-gcc-version-in-qmake-variable-for-pro-file/10) `QMAKE_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION` and `QMAKE_CLANG_MAJOR_VERSION`. So in your `.pro` file you can just write something like:

```
linux-g++:greaterThan(QMAKE_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION, 8):message( "g++ version 9+ found" )
else:linux-clang:greaterThan(QMAKE_CLANG_MAJOR_VERSION, 13):message( "clang version 14+ found" )
```

or add some `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, e.g.

```
linux-g++:greaterThan(QMAKE_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION, 7):QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-deprecated-copy
```

as [Robert Hairgrove](https://forum.qt.io/user/robert-hairgrove) and [Kromignon](https://forum.qt.io/user/kromignon) suggest.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in the 2020ies. :)

Answer (score 1):

I do

```
isEmpty(MGWVER) {
    MGW_MAJ = $$system(echo | gcc -dM -E - | fgrep __GNUC__ | cut -d\" \" -f 3)
    MGW_MIN = $$system(echo | gcc -dM -E - | fgrep __GNUC_MINOR__ | cut -d\" \" -f 3)
    MGWVER =$$MGW_MAJ$$MGW_MIN
    message(MGWVER $$MGWVER)
}
```

It returns "48".
I use it for linking proper boost libraries:

```
USER_BOOST_CFG=mgw$${MGWVER}-mt-s-$$(BOOST_VER)
message($$USER_BOOST_CFG)
LIBS *= -L$$(BOOST_ROOT)/lib
LIBS *= -L$$(BOOST_ROOT)/stage/lib

LIBS *= -lboost_system-$$USER_BOOST_CFG
LIBS *= -lboost_filesystem-$$USER_BOOST_CFG
LIBS *= -lboost_date_time-$$USER_BOOST_CFG
```

effectively giving:
-lboost_system-mgw48-mt-s-1_54

I am on mingw.

Another idea is to look at QMAKESPEC vaariable and parse from it, hint:

```
message(QMAKESPEC $$QMAKESPEC)
SPLITED=$$section(QMAKESPEC, "/", 0, -3)
message(SPLITED $$SPLITED)
```

Comment: this does not work on Qt 5.4 (selected Kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 32bit) `fgrep` is not available.

Comment: fgrep is not a part of qt.
You need http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ .
I recomend installing https://chocolatey.org/ and than 'choco install gnuwin' .
Everything from command line or script

Answer (score 0):

Each compiler vendor use to define some specific symbols that identify the compiler and version. You could make the check using those symbols.

I know, for example, that _MSC_VER gives the version of Microsoft C++ Compiler.

What I also know is that Boost Libraries use this kind of feature selection and adaptation.

You can take a look to Boost Config headers, found in include folder, at path: boost/config/* , specially at select_compiler_config.hpp.

By using those compiler specific symbols, you can make feature selection at preprocessing phase of building the code.

Answer (score 0):

The following macros are defined in my version of gcc and g++

```
#define __GNUC__ 4 
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 0
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 1
```

Additionaly the g++ defines:

```
#define __GNUG__ 4
```