# How to determine a lib or dll is built from which Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

For c++ lib,

I am wondering if there is a way or tool to determine if a lib is for which version of visual studio.

I think different visual studio should use different version of lib. Some libraries does not specify and using the wrong visual studio will have compile/link error.

Comment: It doesn't take much, [Notepad will do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487465/how-to-tell-if-a-lib-was-compiled-with-mt-or-md/19493162#19493162).

Comment: I use notepad, but don't know how to see which version of Visual studio?

Comment: "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" in the example.

Comment: No such kinda strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411854/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-version-of-visual-studio-was-used-to-compile-a

Comment: Puzzled by the results I get. I tried it (using notepad) on 10 libs all compiled in my current project /solution with same options. 4 of them gad this information , 6 not. Using release of debug didn't make any difference.