# Which C standard does Windows SDK 7.1 provide/use (is there an option to switch?)

Tags: c, windows, matlab, sdk

I would like to use Windows SDK 7.1 to compile some C functions in Matlab r2014b.
Now I wonder which C standard the compiler follows?
My previous research in google (no study of manuals) did not yield a result yet.

Furthermore I would like to know if it is possible to change the used standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run the command `cl.exe /?` on the Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt, it reports version number `16.00.30319.01`, which, according to the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233312/finding-version-of-microsoft-c-compiler-from-command-line-for-makefiles) is the version of the compiler that ships with Visual Studio 2010.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), Microsoft did not begin to add support for C99 until Visual Studio 2012, so the compiler that ships with Windows SDK 7.1 must be at most C90-compliant.

Comment: Prior to Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft may have had some C features, but what they provided would not be considered compliant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did say "at most" since I am aware that MS compilers are not known for their compliance to C/++ standards