# Qt: Check gcc Version in pro-File

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding compiler vendor / version using qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801279/finding-compiler-vendor-version-using-qmake)

I need to find out the current gcc-Version in a QT pro-File to set the appropriate QMAKE_CXXFLAGS. How do I do that?